# How can I assign the user input from a form to a outfile

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a new and budding IT student. I recently started a class in HTML, and would like to get some feedback from you guys.

My question is how can I take the information the user inputs into an HTML form field, and store it for further use? here is a snippet of my code:

```
<div id="register" style="background-color:white; height:400px; width:400px; float:left;">
        <p>Sign up to stay up to date</p>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration</legend>
                First Name: <input type="text"><br>
                Last Name: <input type="text"><br>
                Email: <input type="text"><br>
                Phone #: <input type="text"><br>
                Date of birth: <input type="text"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Click to Register" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

my end goal is to have that submit button send it off and store it for further use in a school project.

Comment: I don't see any javascript or php here, so why the tags?

Comment: You can store it into sql database or php variables or javascript variables or even a text file, be more specific in your question

Comment: You will need something like JavaScript, PHP, Scala Play, Django, etc. to handle the data in the form. Either store the values in variables or in a SQL/NoSQL database.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a complete a basic course form w3school or any tutorial related to web.
You can do that in many way, giving below example using jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Formr!</h1>
    <div id="register" style="background-color:white; height:400px; width:400px; float:left;">
        <p>Sign up to stay up to date</p>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration</legend>
                First Name: <input type="text" id="username"><br>
                Last Name: <input type="text"><br>
                Email: <input type="text"><br>
                Phone #: <input type="text"><br>
                Date of birth: <input type="text"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <button type="button" onclick="submit()"> Click to Register</button>

    </div>
    <script>
      function submit(){
        let name = $("#username").val();
        alert(name);
        // simmillary get all the values and do whatever you want like validation or sending in http request to server
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```